# Sinatra cannot find file that is clearly there

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I do not know what to do. It is giving me this error on the line which contains `erb :RUSure` I don't understand why that is different from any other lines where I use `erb :whateverFileName` It is not that it is in a different directory, because it is in the same directory.

My error:

```
2015-05-30T21:50:59.901059+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-05-30 21:50:59 - Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/views/RUSure.erb:
```

In case this is helpful, my tree:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── Rakefile
├── app.rb
├── db
│   ├── migrate
│   │   └── 20150527124739_establish_all.rb
│   └── schema.rb
├── models.rb
└── views
    ├── RUSure.erb
    ├── changePassword.erb
    ├── createQuiz.erb
    ├── deleteStu.erb
    ├── displayAns.erb
    ├── editDB.erb
    ├── error.erb
    ├── getQN.erb
    ├── home.erb
    ├── layout.erb
    ├── noneFound.erb
    ├── select.erb
    ├── setPass.erb
    ├── sucess.erb
    └── test.erb
```

Here is the section that is throwing the error:

```
post '/adminRUSureDelete' do
    admin_check
    @name = params[:name]
    @year = params[:year]
    @band = params[:band]
    if @name == "" and @year == "" and @band == "" then
        var = nil
    elsif @name == "" and @year == "" then
        var = Student.where(band:@band)
    elsif @year == "" and @band == "" then
        var = Student.where(name:@name)
    elsif @name == "" and @band == "" then
        var = Student.where(year:@year)
    elsif @name == "" then
        var = Student.where(year:@year,band:@band)
    elsif @year == "" then
        var = Student.where(band:@band,name:@name)
    elsif @band == "" then
        var = Student.where(year:@year,name:@name)
    else
        var = Student.where(year:@year,name:@name,band:@band)
    end
    if var == nil then
        erb :noneFound
    else
        var.each do |i|
            @list = "#{@list}<p>#{i.name}</p>"
        end
        var.each do |i|
            @send = "#{@send},#{i.id}"
        end
        erb :RUSure # THIS IS THE LINE WHERE IT GIVES ME THE ERROR.
        # It works if any of the other if statements are triggered, but just not here.
    end
end
```

I am willing to add any information that would be helpful.

Comment: A couple of things come to mind: (1) the filename has uppercase characters, check that the name of the file and the name in your code both have the same case; (2) since you have tagged with Heroku, check that the file has been committed to git and pushed to Heroku.

Comment: It has been commited to git and pushed to heroku. I know it is in heroku because when I enter `heroku run bash`  then cd to the views folder, then enter ls, it shows that the file is there. As for case, I am checking that now.

Comment: You were right, it is the case of the erb file name. If you just make that an answer I will make it the accepted answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is using upper case characters. Make sure the filename and the name in your code match in case. If the filename is really e.g. `RUsure.erb` then your code won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it may be looking for the absolute path starting with /app. You may want to make sure you are using it as a relative path or prepending Rails.root to the file path.

Comment: Two things, 1) I am not using rails, 2) anywhere else I use `erb :nameOfErbFile` it works just fine. It is only in this one place that it throws an error.